# How do operating systems handle different character encoding?

Tags: character-encoding, operating-system, system

My operating system is Chinese win10 system, so its character encoding should be the use of GBK, but if I open UTF-8 encoding TXT file, it is still able to display the normal inside Chinese characters. But when I put the file into an English Win10 virtual machine to open the TXT file, the text display has changed.  Why is this happening? How does the operating system handle character coding? Operating system encoding and TXT file character encoding relationship is what?

edit: I use notepad to open the file.
[in english system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4TPC.png)

[in chinese system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDL7m.png)

Comment: Which text editor you are using? Please provide that information as well. Thanks.

Comment: Your question need more information. Please provide the name of the text editor you are using to open the file too. Instead of attaching image always try to provide text in code wherever possible. Thanks.